# separating a single var type variable in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a **var** type variable named ZONE ,and it returns "6001,Kozhikode".I have to get the id 6001 only.how i split these value from this single variable. help me for this query

Thanks & Regards
  Ajmal

Comment: `ZONE.split(',')[0]` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: it works ..I got 6001 separate.But I need this on two places.In one place it works properly & in other not works

Comment: @Ajmal, what's the other place?

Comment: show your code here @Ajmal

Comment: $('#btn').click(function(){ 
       
               ZONEID=$('#zoneId :selected').val();
               CIRCLEID=$('#circleId :selected').val();
                DIVID =$('#divisionId :selected').val();
                 SUBDIVID=$('#subId :selected').val();
                 str_variable=ZONEID;
                toSplit =str_variable.split(",");
              alert(toSplit[0]);
                });    here it wont work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use  [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

```
var str_variable = "6001,Kozhikode";
var toSplit = str_variable.split(",");
```

get

```
alert(toSplit[0]);
```

Comment: answers is useful mark it with green ticks its useful for future users @Ajmal